# How to type © in Sublime Text?

Tags: desktop-computer, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, symbols

This should be straight forward: To type the copyright symbol © in Notepad (on a Windows PC) you press down ALT and then (with alt still pressed down) punch 0, 1, 6, 9 on the keypad. In Sublime text 3 when you do this, no text appears.

Assuming that my version of Sublime Text is fine, what's going wrong?

Comment: The Alt code thing is specific to Windows. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, sorry - forgot the important info :)

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

#1: Don't forget the "0".  As in 0169.

#2:  I myself can do this right here in the browser -->***©***. [ALT]+0+1+6+9 (0169 on the numeric keypad).

My number keys at the top don't seem to do the trick.. It might be my keyboard.  I don't remember this being the case in the before times but whatever.. I have a real keyboard with a numeric keypad.

Find code point for a character or symbol using windows utility ***charmap***

You can see at the bottom of the screenshot that it wants the "0" to pipe this char.

[image]